# How to append clicked element to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this code. Why am I not able to append entire clicked element to a target using jQuery?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
   $(this).html().appendTo($('div'));
});
```

```css
div{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background:khaki;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add Me To Box</button>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is:

```
$(this).html().appendTo($('div'));
```

According to [append](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) you cannot use [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/). Instead, you may use [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) like in:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  //$(this).clone(true).appendTo($('div'));
  $(this).clone().addClass('red').appendTo($('div'));
});
```

```css
div{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background:khaki;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button>Add Me To Box</button>

<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot gaetanoM, just one quick question! is there any way to add a class to appended element as well? I mean juat add a class

Comment: @user1760110 Snippet updated (addClass('red')). Let me know

Answer (score 1):

Change:   `$(this).html().appendTo($('div'));`

to:

```
$('div').append($(this).html())
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than appendTo, use append() :

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $("div").append($(this).html() );
});
```

```css
div{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background:khaki;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add Me To Box</button>

<div></div>
```